# How to initialize a AltiVec register from scalars without using compound literals

Tags: c++, gcc, simd, powerpc, altivec

I have some code like this

```
void op(uint32_t B0, uint32_t B1, uint32_t B2, uint32_t B3)
{
   auto v = (__vector unsigned int){B0, B1, B2, B3};
   ...
}
```

When I compile it, GCC warns that "ISO C++ forbids compound-literals". Is there any other way to initialize an AltiVec `__vector` from multiple scalars without this construct? Or should I just ignore the warning.

I found some IBM documentation that indicated `(__vector unsigned int)(B[0], B[1], B[2], B[3])` (note parens instead of brackets) would work, but GCC rejects this.

The only other thing I can think of is to first place the four scalars into an array and then load it from memory. However that seems like it would be rather slower. I'm basically looking for the equivalent of SSE2's `_mm_set_epi32` intrinsic.

Answer (score 0):

There were two different syntaxes for this back in olden times, both of which might be worth a try:

```
__vector unsigned int v = (__vector unsigned int){ B0, B1, B2, B3 }; // gcc syntax
```

and

```
__vector unsigned int v = (__vector unsigned int)(B0, B1, B2, B3); // Motorola syntax
```

It looks like you already tried the “gcc” syntax (apart from the use of `auto`), but maybe the Motorola syntax might work ?

The only other suggestion I can make if the Motorola syntax does not work is to try using the gcc syntax but compile it as C rather than C++, since there may now be some conflict between C++11 and the gcc-style AltiVec initialisers.

Comment: Sadly the Motorola syntax does not work in C++, and due to the nature of the code in question (it is acting as 100% inlined wrapper around SSE2/AltiVec/NEON registers for C++ code) it is not possible to compile it from C; adding function call overhead here would seriously impair performance.

Comment: Could you use the IBM compiler (xlC) instead of gcc ?